# Python: how to find out what parameters are needed for class of heavy inheritance?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, python-class

A simplified code looks like this:

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self, *, a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
        ...

class Level1_1(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, e, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a=e**2, **kwargs)

class Level1_2(Base):
    def __init__(self, *, f, g, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(c=f, d=g, **kwargs)

class Level2(Level1_1, Level2_2):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

In reality, the inheritance have more levels and are more complicated.

At `Level2` of the example, one needs to **manually check and understand** that `Level1_1` needs an `e` parameter, `Level1_2` needs both `f` and `g` parameters, and `Base` needs a `c` parameter. Therefore, when creating `Level2` objects, one needs to provide `c`, `e`, `f`, `g` parameters. Otherwise, when calling `super().__init__(**kwargs)` there will be issue.

My question is, what is the best practice to handle such manual checks?

My current implementation is following:

```
class Base:
    _keys = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
    _removed_keys = []

    def __init__(self, *, a, b, c, d, **kwargs):
        ...

    def get_keys(self):
    '''
    Code to gather all strings in `_keys` and `_removed_keys` class variables
    of itself and all its parent classes through MRO, and print out or return
    the result, so I can visually see them.
    '''    
        ...

class Level1_1(Base):
    _keys = ['e']
    _removed_keys = ['a']

    def __init__(self, *, e, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(a=e**2, **kwargs)

class Level1_2(Base):
    _keys = ['f', 'g']
    _removed_keys = ['c', 'd']

    def __init__(self, *, f, g, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(c=f, d=g, **kwargs)

class Level2(Level1_1, Level2_2):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Every time I create a new subclass of heavy inheritance, I first run `get_keys()` method to visually see what's needed, but I have a feeling that this is not the most Pythonic way to do it. What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Why does `Level1_1` need an `e` argument, if all it does is pass it as the `a` argument to `super().___init__`?

Comment: As long as you are using `super` [correctly](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/), each class will "extract" the keyword arguments it needs as called.

Comment: @chepner agree that this example might be overly simplified - in reality this is much more complex - I just revised the question. And indeed if I provide correct parameters it runs smoothly. The issue is that as both developer and user, I often have a hard time to know what parameter I need to pass, given the complexity of the class inheritance structures.

Comment: OK, but you still don't need to check anything manually. Whoever actually instantiates a class needs to read the documentation to see which keyword arguments are required, and each `__init__`, as it is called, will raise an exception if any required keyword arguments are missing.

Comment: Very much so indeed - my point is I am both the developer and user of this application, and when I create a new subclass it takes forever to know that,  given it gives an exception one at a time. In real code I also have optional parameters at each level, which makes it much more difficult to remember which class needs what.

Comment: This really sounds more like a documentation problem than something that needs to be handled at runtime.

Comment: Best practice as the author of the code is to create unit tests. Best practice as the user of the code as a library is to read documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a somewhat janky way to get the keyword-only arguments inherited by a `**kwargs` chain using the `inpect` module.

```
import inspect

def get_kw_only_chain(cls):
    kwo_args = []
    for m in cls.mro()[::-1][1:]:
        for kw in inspect.getfullargspec(m).kwonlyargs:
            if kw not in kwo_args:
                kwo_args.append(kw)
    return kwo_args

get_kw_only_chain(Level2)
# returns:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'e']
```

Comment: many thanks man, learned something new from you

Answer (score 0):

The idea of each subclass suplying new kwargs to the superclass does not feel natural.

In a "natural" model, when isntantiating a distant subclass, one would have to pass all non-optional parameters needed for all classes in the hyerarchy - in this case, one instantiating a `Level2`  would need to feed in named parameters for `a, b, c, d, e, f, g` - and not have the intermediate classes derive values for any superclass parameter.

If your code works like this, any intermediate class will have only to worry about picking the specific parameters it needs from the list, and pass along all the others: it is not usual, nor the object of multiple inheritancy in Python that a subclass should have to "know" the parameters of any superclass.

The language pattern `def method(self, *, a, b, **kwargs)`  is  a perfect fit for this way of working - as for any `a` and `b` passed in bulk from a method in a subclass are automatically extracted.

If you really need this unusual behavior, then there is not much running away from a tool to inspect all needed parameters at each class and  see if they are all present at one point or other - since such a tool would have to look at the parameters *used* when calling `super()` I can only recommend a method that would use the `dis` module (disassembler) and inspect the text generated by its output to see if all parameters needed by the immediate superclass in the `__mro__`  are included in the `super()` call .

Then put some trigger to run this only as a development-time task. If these are in submodules `if __name__=="__main__":`  could be such a guard: you'd run the modules with the subclasses directly to get the output of your inspection tools.